# Total over time query

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer, kql

In Log Analytics I can write the following query:

```
requests
| where timestamp > ago(30d)
| summarize count() by bin(timestamp, 5m)
```

And each bin will have the requests count during that time frame.

```
bin 1 -> 5 req
bin 2 -> 2 req
bin 3 -> 8 req
```

I would like to have the total overall over time, as in:

```
bin 1 -> 5  req
bin 2 -> 7  req (bin1 + bin2)
bin 3 -> 15 req (bin1 + bin2 + bin3)
```

How can I achieve that with Kusto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try using `row_cumsum()`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/rowcumsumfunction

```
datatable(dummy:int, timestamp:datetime)
[
    1, datetime(2019-10-06 00:00),
    1, datetime(2019-10-06 00:01),
    1, datetime(2019-10-06 00:02),
    1, datetime(2019-10-06 00:03),
    1, datetime(2019-10-06 00:04),
    1, datetime(2019-10-06 06:00),
    1, datetime(2019-10-06 06:01),
    1, datetime(2019-10-06 12:00),
    1, datetime(2019-10-06 12:00),
    1, datetime(2019-10-06 12:02),
    1, datetime(2019-10-06 12:01),
    1, datetime(2019-10-06 12:04),
    1, datetime(2019-10-06 12:01),
    1, datetime(2019-10-06 12:02),
    1, datetime(2019-10-06 12:02),
]
| summarize count() by bin(timestamp, 5m)
| order by timestamp asc 
| project timestamp, c = row_cumsum(count_)
```

-->

```
| timestamp                   | c  |
|-----------------------------|----|
| 2019-10-06 00:00:00.0000000 | 5  |
| 2019-10-06 06:00:00.0000000 | 7  |
| 2019-10-06 12:00:00.0000000 | 15 |
```